# How do I access superclass's classmethod?

Tags: python, class

I really need to find some way to superclass's classmethod from subclasses of that superclass.

here is the generalized code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A init"

    @classmethod
    def _method(cls):
        print cls
        return cls()


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B init"

class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        print "C init"

    @classmethod
    def _method(cls):
        print "calling super(C)'s classmethod"
        return super(C)._method()

c = C._method()
```

which results in :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27x64/testclass", line 26, in <module>
    c = C._method()
  File "C:/Python27x64/testclass", line 22, in _method
    return super(C)._method()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_method'
```

note that from `c = C._method()`, I am calling uninitialized class `C`'s classmethod. and from `C`, I call also uninitialized class `A` or `B` (traversing through the MRO)'s classmethod.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `cls` variable in the `super` call:

```
class C(B):
    def __init__(self):
        print "C init"

    @classmethod
    def _method(cls):
        print "calling super(C)'s classmethod"
        return super(C, cls)._method()
```